# Receiving OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error in app running in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker

I have a React/Flask app running within a Docker container. There is no issue with me building the project using docker-compose, and running the app itself in the container. Where I am running into issues is a particular API route that is supposed to fetch user profiles from the DB, encrypt the values in a text file, and return to the frontend for download. The encryption script is written in C, though the API route is written in Python. When I try and encrypt through the app running in Docker, I am given the following error message:

**OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './app/Crypto/encrypt.exe'**

I know the following command works in the CLI if invoked outside of the Docker Container (still invoked at the same directory level as it would in app):

```
./app/Crypto/encrypt.exe -k ./app/Crypto/secretkey -i ./profile.txt -o ./profile.encr
```

I am using the following Python code to invoke the command in the API route which is where it fails:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(f"./app/Crypto/encrypt.exe -k ./app/Crypto/secretkey -i ./{profile.profile_name}.txt -o ./{profile.profile_name}.encr", shell=True)
```

The Dockerfile for my backend is pasted below:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app

ENV FLASK_APP=main.py

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I have tried to tackle the issue a few different ways:

- By default my Docker Container was built with Architecture of ARM64. I read that the OS Error was caused by Architecture not being AMD64, so I rebuilt the container with AMD64 and it gave me the same error.
- In case this was a permissions error, I ran chmod +rwx on encrypt.exe through the Dockerfile when building the container. Pretty sure it has nothing to do with permissions especially as it still failed.
- I added a shebang (#!/bin/bash) to the script as well as to the Dockerfile.

At the end of the day I know I am failing when using subprocess.Popen, so I am positive I must be missing something when invoking the script using Python, or there is a configuration in my Docker Container that is preventing this functionality. My machine is a Macbook Pro which the script runs fine on. The script has also successfully been utilized on a machine running Linux.

Any chances folks have seen similar issues arise with this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the `encrypt.exe` get built?  What processor architecture and OS is it built for?  Potentially rebuilding it in the Dockerfile could avoid this issue.

Comment: It is built with instructions from a Makefile! I think this is an excellent point. I have rebuilt the exe using the Makefile directly in the Dockerfile. The trick now is getting the packages needed for the C program to run and encrypt the content within the Docker container as well. I think this is the right path, will update once I am able to successfuly build the exe and test it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to David Maze's comment on this, I followed the lead that maybe the executable I wanted to run needed to be built within the Dockerfile. I destroyed my original container, added in a step to run the Makefile that generates the executable, and finally ran the program through the app running in the Docker container. This did the trick! Not sure as to why the executable needed to be compiled within the Docker container, but running 'make' on the Makefile within the Dockerfile did the trick.